# Stripe server-side redirect blocked - Rails/React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, cors

I'm integrating Stripe to accept payments on my website but I'm getting an error when redirecting to Stripe payment form from Rails backend API. Is there any configuration I need to make it work?
Below is what I did

**PaymentController.rb**

```
class Api::PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        price = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
        @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
            customer: current_user.stripe_customer_id,
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: [{
                price: price.stripe_price_id,
                quantity: params[:quantity],
              }],
            allow_promotion_codes: true,
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: "#{api_success_url}?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            cancel_url: api_cancel_url
          })
        redirect_to @session.url, status: 303, allow_other_host: true
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#root'

  namespace :api do
   
    resources :listings, only: [:show, :index, :new, :create]

    post '/create-checkout-session', to: "payments#create"
    get "/success", to: "payments#success"
    get "cancel", to: "payments#cancel"
  end
end
```

**cors.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "*"
    resource "*",
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete]
  end
end
```

**Checkout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PulseLoader from '../loaders/pulse_loader';
import ListingShowFooter from '../listings/listing_show/listing_show_footer';
import axios from "axios";

class Checkout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
 
      total: 100,
      days: 7
    }

    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchListing(this.props.listingId);
  }


  async submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      price: this.state.total,
      quantity: this.state.days,
    }
    const response = await axios.post("/api/create-checkout-session", data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    })
   const res = await response.data;
   return res;
  }

  render() {
    let { currentUser, listing, bookingParams } = this.props;
    if (this.state.loading || !listing) {
      return (
        <div className="loader__container">
          <PulseLoader />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    return (
      <div className="checkout__container">
         <form className="checkout__btn-wrapper" onSubmit={this.submit}>
            <button type="submit" className="checkout__btn" >Agree and book</button>
         </form>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkout;
```

**The error I'm getting**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwDYF.png)

I've added Rack CORS to allow resource sharing between the frontend and backend.

Comment: It is likely that it is not about CORS between your front and back apps, that is about CORS between your apps and stripe

Comment: I solved the issue by sending the Stripe URL to the front end and then opening it with JavaScript.